# Batch insert SQL statement

Tags: mysql, batch-file, bulkinsert

I have say 100 rows data to insert in MySQL database table.
But i dont want to write all 100 `INSERT` statements.
Is there any bulk insert Statement in SQL ???
Please help with code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'), ...
```

And please read [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) first next time

Comment: Sorry, actually I dint deleted it. I just modified the query as code parts.

Comment: @Sai Kalyan Akshinthala: ah, got it. We made 2 edits in the same time, and yours was first, sorry

Answer (score 3):

As the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) states:

> `INSERT` statements that use `VALUES` syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```

Furthermore, from the section on [speed of `INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html):

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, use [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements with multiple `VALUES` lists to insert several rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statements. If you are adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the [`bulk_insert_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) variable to make data insertion even faster. See [Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).