# Need SQL to Sort table based on another list of array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get list of item from my table but in sorted order and list must be sorted as below:

Assume I have fields named as "productid" and "productname" and table as below records

```
1. milk
2. pizza
3. boll
```

And I have another list in array such as

```
boll
pizza
milk
```

Now I want to sort table list based on array value and get below list"

```
3. boll
2. pizza
1. mike
```

Is there any SQL which can do what I need? Or I need to do it manually via coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this if with the following bit of pseudo code, from your application code

```
sqlexecuter.run(
"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORDERED_ENTRIES(
       ORDER_ENTRY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       PRODUCT_NAME varchar(255) --Put the same amount size as your other table
)")
```

Then in your code insert them into that table, in a similar way to this

```
for(i:lenght(myProductArray))
    sqlexecuter.run
    ("
        INSERT INTO ORDERED_ENTRIES
        VALUES("+myProductArray[i]+")"
    )
```

And then select like this

```
sqlexecuter.select(
"
SELECT OE.ORDER_ENTRY, PT.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE AS PT, ORDERED_ENTRIES AS OE
WHERE
    OE.PRODUCT_NAME = PT.PRODUCT_NAME
ORDER BY OE.ORDER_ENTRY
");
```

Comment: As an extra tip, you should do a batch insert if you can, to insert everything in one go.  Similar to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429348/batch-insert-sql-statement